# Set theory vocabulary: the unique subsets which compose a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

I'm struggling for the correct vocabulary/notation for the following situation. Let's say `S` is a (very simple) set with the following composition:

```
S = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
```

Now, there are two subsets which compose this set, `A` and `B`:

```
A = {1, 2}
B = {3, 4, 5, 6}
```

Obviously, A is a subset of S, $A \subseteq S$, and B is a subset of S, $B \subseteq S$.

Not only are A and B subsets of S, these are subsets which uniquely compose S, i.e.

$A \cup B = S$ and $A \cap B =  \varnothing$

(1) What is the vocabulary used to describe these type of subsets? A "unique" subset?

(2) If there is no special terminology, how would one best convey this concept notationally?

e.g.

$A \subseteq S$ and $B \subseteq S$ s.t. $A \cap B =  \varnothing$

maybe be one possibility, but it doesn't show that the union of A and B *are* the set S...

Comment: A and B form a [partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set) of S?

Comment: The word "partition" is what you want.  An obvious caveat is that there will be many different possible partitions as one shouldn't think.  Let $A, B$ be partions of $C$ mean that $A$ and $B$ have actually been *specified*.  It hasn't be specified if A = {1,2,3} B ={4,5} or if A = {4} and B={1,2,3,5} or ... whatever.

Comment: It's also worth being aware that equivalence relations define partitions of sets. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation

Comment: You should probably add to your question $A\cup B=S$ which you intend but don't write. The requirements are $A\cup B=S$ and $A\cap B=\emptyset$.

Comment: @ProducerofBS Edited

Answer (score 5):

I think you are looking for a *[partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set)*:

> A partition of a set X is a set of nonempty subsets of X such that every element x in X is in exactly one of these subsets...
>
> Equivalently, a family of sets P is a partition of X if and only if all of the following conditions hold:
>
> - The family P does not contain the empty set
> - The union of the sets in P is equal to X ...
> - The intersection of any two distinct sets in P is empty
>
> [Quoted from Wikipedia]

Answer (score 3):

The standard way to say this is that $\{A,B\}$ is a *partition* of $S$.  In general, a partition of a set $S$ is a set of nonempty subsets of $S$ which are pairwise disjoint (the intersection of any two of them is empty) and whose union is $S$.

Another way to say this is that $A$ is a subset of $S$ and $B$ is the *complement* of $A$; that is, $B$ consists of exactly those elements of $S$ that are not in $A$.  Some commonly used notations for the complement of $A$ (in $S$) are $S\setminus A$, $S-A$, or $A^c$.  So your condition could be stated as $A\subseteq S$ and $B=S\setminus A$.